# Why transmission displays any port as closed even all ports are opened?

Tags: transmission

I am using transmission for torrenting. I opened all of my ports. I become root and check it with "ufw status". Result is -> Status: inactive.

I also allowed default transmission port (51413) from router interface:
Port Triggering and Port forwarding for my ip active both ways

I still see it as closed when test it from transmission.

Comment: Are you behind CGNAT? See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier-grade_NAT and check your router's status page to ensure that your router has obtained a "real IP address" and not one of the "private IP addresses": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network

Comment: my isp looks like do something like that. It gives me kind of ip which is given to many users instead of one user.

Comment: If you live in Turkey like me (I am just guessing from your last name), you have to "rent" a ***static IP*** from your ISP. It is roughly 3 $ per month. This is the only way to have a _unique IP_ and not a "shared" one.

Comment: 3 dolar çokmuş amca.